# Android studio runs very slow in my laptop

Tags: android, android-studio

android studio runs very slow in my laptop. I have an acer laptop with 4GB RAM, Intel i3 processor with 1.7 GHz, and also 1TB hard disk.
But while try to runs android studio it runs very slowly. Is my processor is reason for that because i have a Intel i3 processor with **1.7GHz**.?
is 1.7 GHz necessary for running android studio?
or what will be the problem?

Comment: Pls refer http://geek.moneylover.me/android-studio-eliminate-shutter-n-lag/

Comment: kill/remove unnecessary processes in background task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements), Minimum requirements for Android Studio :

### **Windows**

- Microsoft® Windows® 8/7/Vista/2003 (32 or 64-bit)
- 2 GB RAM minimum, 4 GB RAM recommended
- 400 MB hard disk space
- At least 1 GB for Android SDK, emulator system images, and caches
- 1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution
- Java Development Kit (JDK) 7
- Optional for accelerated emulator: Intel® processor with support for
  Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit
  functionality

Now this is minimum requirements so you should use better than this requirements.

I recommended to expand your RAM to 8 GB. I have RAM of 8 GB and its working fine.

Also you can improve android studio performance using this [link](http://geek.moneylover.me/android-studio-eliminate-shutter-n-lag/) .

Thanks.